# Javascript/CSS Show/Hide Sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a loader gif I'm trying to show/hide for ajax calls to indicate progress. It works for one function and not the other, oddly enough.

```js
function showThis(id) {

  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hideThis(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#testKey").click(function(event) {
    // NEXT LINE DOESN'T WORK
    showThis('loader2');
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/api/?action=testKey",
      data: {
        exchange: jQuery('#setExchange').val(),
        key: jQuery('#setKey').val(),
        secret: jQuery('#setSecret').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (!data.error) {
          if (data.keyValid == true) {
            alert("API Key is valid");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid key and/or secret.");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Error: " + data.errorMsg);
        }
      }
    });
    hideThis('loader2');
    return false;
  });
});

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#setSave').click(function(event) {
    // THIS WORKS
    showThis("loader2");
    jQuery.post(
      '/api/?action=bcSaveSettings', {
        exchange: jQuery('#setExchange').val(),
        key: jQuery('#setKey').val(),
        secret: jQuery('#setSecret').val(),
      },
      function() {
        var newKey = jQuery('#setKey').val();
        var newSecret = jQuery('#setSecret').val();
        var exchangeNum = jQuery('#setExchange').val();
        var exchangeName = jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").text();
        jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").attr('dat', newKey);
        jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").attr('dat2', newSecret);
        if (jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").length > 0 && newKey.length < 1 && newSecret.length < 1) {
          jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").remove();
        } else if (jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").length < 1 && newKey.length > 0 && newSecret.length > 0) {
          jQuery("#depExchange").append(jQuery('<option>', {
            value: exchangeNum,
            text: exchangeName
          }));
        }
        hideThis("loader2");
        alert("Settings saved");
      }
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#loader1 {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#loader2 {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: loader_dot;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes loader_dot {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="testKey">test1</button>
<BR />
<BR />
<button id="setSave">test2</button>


<div id="loader2" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Originally I was using jquery hide/show but got the same behavior. Note: Both ajax calls work properly but the loader only shows for the one as indicated in the JS comments.

Comment: Try `$( document ).ready()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the place where you are hiding the loader.you Need to hide the loader when the API results are emerged. Modified your code according to that.

```js
function showThis(id) {
  console.log('12' + id);
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hideThis(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#testKey").click(function(event) {
    // NEXT LINE DOESN'T WORK
    showThis('loader2');
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/api/?action=testKey",
      data: {
        exchange: jQuery('#setExchange').val(),
        key: jQuery('#setKey').val(),
        secret: jQuery('#setSecret').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (!data.error) {
          hideThis("loader2");
          if (data.keyValid == true) {
            alert("API Key is valid");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid key and/or secret.");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Error: " + data.errorMsg);
          hideThis("loader2");
          return false;
        }

      }
    });
    //hideThis('loader2');
    //return false;
  });
});

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#setSave').click(function(event) {
    // THIS WORKS
    showThis("loader2");
    jQuery.post(
      '/api/?action=bcSaveSettings', {
        exchange: jQuery('#setExchange').val(),
        key: jQuery('#setKey').val(),
        secret: jQuery('#setSecret').val(),
      },
      function() {
        var newKey = jQuery('#setKey').val();
        var newSecret = jQuery('#setSecret').val();
        var exchangeNum = jQuery('#setExchange').val();
        var exchangeName = jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").text();
        jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").attr('dat', newKey);
        jQuery("#setExchange option:selected").attr('dat2', newSecret);
        if (jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").length > 0 && newKey.length < 1 && newSecret.length < 1) {
          jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").remove();
        } else if (jQuery("#depExchange option[value='" + exchangeNum + "']").length < 1 && newKey.length > 0 && newSecret.length > 0) {
          jQuery("#depExchange").append(jQuery('<option>', {
            value: exchangeNum,
            text: exchangeName
          }));
        }
        hideThis("loader2");
        alert("Settings saved");
      }
    );
    //event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#loader1 {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#loader2 {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: loader_dot;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes loader_dot {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="testKey">test1</button>
<BR />
<BR />
<button id="setSave">test2</button>


<div id="loader2">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need call `hideThis('loader2');` in `ajax() callback`.
Maybe `success` or `error`, even `complete`.

Example:

```
showThis()
jQuery.ajax({
  // `success` or `error`
  complete: function () {
    // call `hide` when the `callback` called
    hideThis()
  }
})
```

> Your code just call `show` and `hide`, It's doesn't wait for `ajax` execute.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your first button code is "hideThis" function.
Show function is working fine but is instantly followed by "hide".

Move hide function in "success" code of ajax post and it should be fine.